# Spring Data REST - How to sort an entity by JSON ignored field?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-rest

I am using Spring Data REST and I have the following entity in my project.

```
@Data
@Entity
public class Loan{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @JsonIgnore
    private Long createdDate;

    private Long amount;

    private Long repaymentStartDate;

}
```

Now I want to sort the loans by the `createdDate` which will be automatically filled and JSONIgnored to prevent it from being updated. But I am unable to sort the loans by the `createdDate` when I call the endpoint `loans?sort=createdDate`.

How do I fix this?

Here is my repository:

```
public interface LoanRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Loan, Long>{

}
```

Comment: How does the restcontroller looks like? Please add the code to you question.

Comment: Since I am using Spring Data REST there is no need to write separate controller. Spring will generate it when I extend the repository interface.

Comment: When the field is annotated with ‘@JsonIgnore’ the field is not visible for the user. So it is clear that it is not possible to sort the result by something the user cannot see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To workaround try to replace `@JsonIgnore` to `@JsonProperty(access = READ_ONLY)`. It prevents `createdDate` from changing but remains it in the json body.

**UPDATED**

For Spring Boot 1.5.10+ instead of `@JsonProperty(access = READ_ONLY)` you can use `@JsonIgnoreProperties("createdDate")` on top of the entity.